# Data is not saved to the database in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I fill and submit the form, the data is not persisted into my Mysql database.

Do you know what I have done wrong?

My address controller look like this :

```
App/Address
......




public function store(Request $request)
            {
                $this->validate($request,[
                    'addressline'=>'required',
                    'city'=>'required',
                    'state'=>'required',
                    'zip'=>'required|integer',
                    'contry'=>'required',
                    'phone'=>'required|integer',

                ]);

                Auth::user()->address()->create($request->all());
                Address::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->back();

            }
```

The route :

```
 Route::post('shipping-info','CheckoutController@store')->name('checkout.shipping');
```

The Address model :

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=['addressline','city','state','zip','phone','country'];
}
```

The Blade view:

```
 @extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 small-centered columns">
        <h3>Shipping Info</h3>

              {!! Form::open(['route' => 'checkout.shipping', 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true, 'data-parsley-validate'=>'']) !!}


..........

{{ Form::submit('Proceed to Payment', array('class' => 'button success')) }}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Can you check what you are getting in request by doing `dd($request->all());`

Comment: when i check using dd ,, the browser just reload dont get format json

Comment: As suggested by zuif, add dd() to know what data actually inside request. To avoid redirect, just call `die()` before redirect.

Comment: From your route, when you post to shipping-info, you are calling store method of CheckoutController not store method of AddressController
Except the CheckoutController's store method calls the store method of AddressController, this wont work and I wonder why you would take this approach. It's better you change

Route::post('shipping-info','CheckoutController@store')->name('checkout.shipping');

to

Route::post('shipping-info','AddressController@store');

Comment: In addition, what do you need this line for?

    Auth::user()->address()->create($request->all());

Answer (score 0):

If your intention was to call the store method of the AddressController then the error is in your route. You should change

```
Route::post('shipping-info','CheckoutController@store')->name('checkout.shipping');
```

to

```
Route::post('shipping-info','AddressController@store');
```

In addition, I am not sure why you need this

```
Auth::user()->address()->create($request->all());
```